# Swipe gesture recognizer swift

Tags: ios, swift2, uiswipegesturerecognizer, ios9.1

I have been looking on the internet for a few hours now on how to use the Swipe Gesture Recognizer. I do not want to code it, because I have tried nearly every single example and that doesn't work. However, I know that there is a Swipe Gesture Recognizer in the object library, but it doesn't seem to work. Can somebody please show me a link to a place where I can use the Swipe Gesture Recognizer from the Object Library or show me how to do it?

Thanks,

Ben

(If I am being to broad for some reason, or you don't like my question, please do not -1 this, just comment and I will make the change, please).

Crash Log:
2016-01-09 10:59:33.392 Capitals[250:14059] -[Capitals.Alabama1 handleSwipes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14f695150
2016-01-09 10:59:33.397 Capitals[250:14059] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Capitals.Alabama1 handleSwipes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14f695150'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x184bdcf48 0x19984ff80 0x184be3c5c 0x184be0c00 0x184ae4cac 0x18a6eb330 0x18a314b5c 0x18a1a285c 0x18a6ec70c 0x18a1618b8 0x18a15e63c 0x18a1a06cc 0x18a19fcc8 0x18a1704a4 0x18a16e76c 0x184b94544 0x184b93fd8 0x184b91cd8 0x184ac0ca0 0x18fb40088 0x18a1d8ffc 0x10008a264 0x19a0928b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

(Handle Swipes is the name of the function)

Here is the code:

import UIKit

class Alabama1: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let reveal = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleSwipes"))
    let next = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleSwipes"))

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    reveal.direction = .Up
    next.direction = .Left

    view.addGestureRecognizer(reveal)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(next)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func handleSwipes(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    if (sender.direction == .Up) {
        label.text = "Motgomery"
    }

}





}
```

Comment: You said, you tried something and it doesn't work. Can you include the code that you used ?

Comment: Could I include the tutorial I copied it from? Here it is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9r1UFNeVuFA . I changed the "var" to "let" to work with the latest version of swift. @MidhunMP

Comment: So what not worked ? Did you followed all those steps mentioned in the tutorial ?

Comment: @MidhunMP I followed all of the steps in the tutorial, and when I tried it out, it crashed at the function part. I double checked the function, but it was exactly the same as the video. I checked the function because according to xcode, my app crashed there.

Comment: Please include the code that you are using for adding swipe gesture and the selector method. Include the crash log you got

Comment: @MidhunMP Editing the code now!

Comment: You typed the selector wrongly, you need to modify it. Your method takes one argument, so you should use `Selector("handleSwipes:")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing semicolumn in adding event. Try like so:

```
let reveal = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleSwipes:"))
let next = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleSwipes:"))
```

Comment: @NickCatlib Thank you so much
!

Answer (score 1):

in swift3 Version :

```
   let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MainMenuViewController.handleSwipes(_sender:)))
```